# Index Error for a code that extracts pixel data from pictures

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, matrix

I used the Python Imaging Library and Numpy to run the following code that extracts pixel data from specific region of interest in a picture. The following code is supposed to take multiple pictures of dimensions w by h, cut by the margin of width a(horizontal) and b(vertical) and create a new matrix that only includes the pixel data inside the margin. The data size is simply the number of pictures on which I want to iterate this process.

However, when I run this on command prompt using Notepad++, the prompt returns:

IndexError: index 982 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 975

Any ideas on how I could fix this error? The common solution to these problems were fixing the ranges, but I can't find any problem with my range(regarding the area of interest). Thanks:)

```
def edit_data(data_size,a,b):

    d = data_size
    sample_file = im.open("C:\Research\data_1\sample (1).jpg")
    w, h = sample_file.size
    print(w,h)

    gray_sample = np.zeros((d,(w-2*a),(h-2*a)))


    for i in range(0, d):
        file = im.open("C:\Research\data_1\sample (%d).jpg" % (i+1))

        for j in range(a, (w-a)):

            for k in range(b, (h-b)):
                r, g, b = file.getpixel((j, k))

                gray_sample[i][(j-a)][(k-b)] = (r*0.299 + g*0.587 + b*0.114)/255

    return gray_sample
#test the function
a = edit_data(1, 30, 30)
print(a.size)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the message could not be much more explicit. One dimension of your array is 975 and your code is trying to access the 982nd element. I suspect you may have the *x* and *y* axes the wrong way around somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Indeed, I actually made a mistake when I declared the numpy array of the gray_sample variable:)